# Login page is not working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am uploading my website in a web server and my login is not working.On localhost everything was fine.Now when i put the correct username and password it gives me That username/password combination is incorrect.When i put the incorrect password it give this again.The other validations work fine and my code : 
log in.php

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php'; 

if(empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($username)=== true || empty($password) === true ) {
    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username & password';
}else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[]='We cant find that username.Have you registered?';
}else if (user_active($username) === false) {
    $errors[]='You havent activated your account!';
}else {

    if(strlen($password) > 32) {
        $errors[] = 'Password too long';

    }
    $login = login($username, $password);
    if($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect';

    }else{
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
header('Location: index2.php');
exit();
    }       
    }
}else {
$errors[] = 'No data received';
    }
    include 'overall/headerr.php';
if (empty($errors)=== false) {
    ?>
    <h2>We tried to log you in, but...</h2>
    <?php
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>
```

users.php

```
function login($username, $password){
        $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

        $username = sanitize($username);
        $password = md5($password);

        return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'"), 0)==1) ? $user_id : false;
}
function logged_in() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;
}
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
  return (mysql_result( mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` ='$username' "), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
  }
function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` =1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}
general.php
<?php 
function sanitize($data) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}

function output_errors($errors) { 
$output = array();
foreach($errors as $error) {
$output[] = '<li>'. $error .'</li>';
}
return '<ul>' . implode ('', $output) . '</ul>';
}
?>
```

init.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
$errors = array() ; 
?>
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Stacking your query functions makes *debugging* quite difficult, ie. `mysql_result( mysql_query() )` Have a look at the links provided by @Fred-ii- as a start. You need to make sure that you're connecting to the database properly, and that your queries aren't returning errors. If everything is *working* on localhost, then I'd suspect the database is in question on your prod server.

Comment: On another note, returning `mysql_real_escape_string()` within the `sanitize()` function is redundant. Why not simply call `mysql_real_escape_string()` directly? Or even simpler: `$_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);` and take care of the entire array in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making your code long & complicated?

I use this simple and nice code:

```
<?php
session_start();                    /* Start a session on browser */
require('connect.php');             /* Get database-connection script */
$username = $_POST['username'];     /* Define variable ' $username ' */
$password = $_POST['password'];     /* Define variable ' $password ' */

/* Check if username or password is empty */
if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    /* If one of the fields are empty, send user back. */
    echo 'afar'; // All fields are required
} else {
    /* Select usernames & passwords from our database */
    $check_accpass = $dbh->query('SELECT username,password FROM `users` WHERE `username`='.$dbh->quote($username).' AND `password`='.$dbh->quote($password).'')->fetchAll();
  /* Check if username & password has any matches in our database */
  if($check_accpass) {
     echo 'success';
     /* IF they do, set $username to $_SESSION['USERNAME'] and same with password */
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
     $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

     // Set cookies
     // name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly
     setcookie("username", $username, time() + (172800 * 30), "/", NULL, TRUE, TRUE); /* 2 days = 48 hours */
     setcookie("password", $password, time() + (172800 * 30), "/", NULL, TRUE, TRUE); /* 2 days = 48 hours */
     // Send user to root
     header('location:/');
  } else {
     /* if no matches are found, print the text below */
     echo 'wuop'; // wrong username or password
  }
}
?>
```